# mysql query very slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very slow query because using ORDER BY. Now i understand why it is slow but i have no idea how i make it faster.

The table got like 13,000,000 records. (the reason why it is slow)

Tables 30
Rows 13,591,548
Data 1.3 GiB
Indexes 265.2 MiB
Total 1.5 GiB
Overhead 96 B

```
$sql3 =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config LIMIT 1");
$row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3);
$log=$row3['con_log'];
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT sl_start,sl_id FROM scan_list2 WHERE sl_scanned='0' ORDER BY sl_id LIMIT 40");
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)){
echo "crk|".$row2['sl_start']."|".$log."-";
$sl_id = $row2['sl_id'];
mysql_query("UPDATE scan_list2 SET sl_scanned='1' WHERE sl_id='$sl_id'");
```

Is there any better solution for this problem?

Comment: 1. Table schema 2. `EXPLAIN` 3. PS: you may perform a single update using `WHERE sl_id IN (...)

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First review your table indexes.

In php you don't need to perform one update for each 40 row, run your `update` then `select` and after, perform a loop to show information about rows from `select`, like:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE scan_list2 SET sl_scanned = '1' WHERE sl_scanned = '0' ORDER BY sl_id LIMIT 40");

$sql3 =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config LIMIT 1");
$row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3);

$log=$row3['con_log'];

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT sl_start,sl_id FROM scan_list2 WHERE sl_scanned = '1' ORDER BY sl_id DESC LIMIT 40");

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)){
    echo "crk|".$row2['sl_start']."|".$log."-";
}
```

Comment: What if you not only need to change the flag but actually peform some job over the data selected? `echo "crk|".$row2['sl_start']."|".$log."-";` --- this is a trivial example from the question that your solution doesn't take into account.

Comment: in this case you will not have many options besides checking the table indexes and try to improve performance on the PHP side using PDO or mysqli instead of mysql_query

Comment: well, using proper indexes **IS** a solution, not just an option. Even for `UPDATE` you still need them.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead change your UPDATE query to update all the records in one update by adding JOIN

```
UPDATE scan_list2 
INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT sl_start,sl_id 
            FROM scan_list2 
            WHERE sl_scanned='0' 
            ORDER BY sl_id 
            LIMIT 40
        ) b ON scan_list2.sl_id = b.sl_id 
SET sl_scanned='1'
```